# First time writing Pseudocode, can someone help me?

Tags: python, variable-assignment, pseudocode

My assignment is to write Pseudocode for a program I was told to create.
The Color Mixer program in Python. Here are two examples of how to write the
Psuedocode out of the book I was told to read.

```
Declare Integer age

Display "What is your age?"

Input age

Display "Here is the value that you entered:"

Display age

If temperature < 40 Then
   Display "A little cold, isn't it?"
Else
   Display "Nice weather we're having."
End If
```

By that logic, I came up with this Psuedocode for the color mixer program I wrote.

```
Declare String color1, color2, color3

Display "Enter Primary Color"
input color1

Display "Enter Secondary Color"
input color2

If color1 == "blue" and color2 == "red" or color1 == "red" and color2 == "blue" Then
    Display "When you mix Red and Blue, you get Purple."

Else If color1 == "yellow" and color2 == "blue" or color1 == "blue" and color2 == "yellow" Then
    Display "When you mix Yellow and Blue, you get Green."

Else If color1 == "red" and color2 == "yellow" or color1 == "yellow" and color2 == "red" Then
    Display "When you mix Red and Yellow, you get Orange."

Else
    Display "Enter a correct color"
End If
```

Would this be the correct way to write the Pseudocode?

Comment: Pseudocode isn't standardized, so nobody could tell e.g. if equality operator is written as `==` or `=` or if the `End If` is used correctly.

Comment: Seem fine to me but this is likely subject subjective rather than objective.

Comment: Fine, I think. You can surround the condition checks in the `If` statement with parentheses to avoid any ambiguity. Also, Pseudocode doesn't need to be too specific with the actual programming syntax. It's better to prioritize clarity over using the exact programming constructs.